# Android, disable scrollbar on the right side of the listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll, scrollbar

I have list view which is populated with my list item view. On the right of each row i have a add to cart button:

[image]

when i try to click my button, list view scrolls down or up, how i can prevent scrolling at the right side of list view? i want scroll work when i move list view with my fingers up or down except over my button.

i also tried setting `android:scrollbars="none"` and `productListView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);`

Here is my list view xml code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/product_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. I need to remove `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` for not showing scrollbar at the right side of listview